# RAISERROR and returning error message to the calling application

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

Assuming Asp.Net app calls procedure dbo.ApprovePost and  @@ERROR contains a value greater than 0, then the following code  will be executed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ApprovePost
      …
IF @@ERROR > 0
 BEGIN
     RAISERROR(‘Approval of post failed’, 16, 1)
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ApprovePost
     RETURN 99
 END

COMMIT TRANSACTION ApprovePost
```

a) I don’t know much about stored procedures, but I thought that when RAISERROR raises an error, then no code after RAISERROR will be executed, since procedure will exit the moment error was raised?!

b) I assume RAISERROR function will return the error message back to calling Asp.Net application?

c) If so, then why does procedure also need to return value 99 to indicate failure ( BTW – I assume this value is returned to the calling Asp.Net application )?

d) And why value 99? Why not 100 or any other value?

thanx

Answer (score 2):

Calling `RAISERROR` with a severity level higher than 10, it is 16 in your case, causes a `SqlException` in ADO.NET (severity levels 10 or lower are informational messages only), so returning 99 is pointless unless the exception is caught and you still can access the return parameter on the `SqlCommand` object (not sure it is accessible - haven't tested it).

Why 99? It's clearly some 'magic' value for the calling code.